# Magento - set product media image attribute programmatically

Tags: image, magento, attributes

I have custom media image attribute 'prozr_img'. When i try add image to product programmatically with code of this attribute, image uploaded, but attribute not set.

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, 'prozr_img', false, false);
```

$filepath is correct since image uploads correctly. Need a way to set this image as image for 'prozr_img' attribute for this product (same wasy as thumbnail etc).

Comment: does the attribute prozr exists ? with group_id 10 ?

Comment: Yes, and i can manually select him for photo in product images tab.

Comment: do you see the link between image and product in the database ? if no, do you save the product after adding the image ?

Comment: I see image in product images tab and i save product after.